# I decided or I would decide

Tags: tense

*The next Friday I will tell you how **I decided/would decide** regarding your proposal.*

Not sure what tense to use in the second part of my sentence. Is the future in the past appropriate option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Would decide" sounds like a Present Unreal conditional.

If you want to use a verb, you can say,

> [I will tell you what I decide](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=Qep8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=%22will+tell+you+what+I+decide%22&source=bl&ots=NnFnrDNlF4&sig=Et8_dwh5ua1lw_6ko3Lca49Dnyo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB4szThZ_ZAhVBniwKHVxeC6wQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22will%20tell%20you%20what%20I%20decide%22&f=false)

But you can also say,

> I will tell you my decision next Friday.

If you need to sound formal, you can say,

> I will inform you of my decision next Friday.

(e. g., [here](http://www.nbcsports.com/boston/boston-celtics/blakely-kevin-durant-seriously-considering-boston-celtics), Kevin Durant says that "he will inform them of his decision as early as Monday")

Comment: "what" because you are informing your conclusion (what it is, either yes or no), while "how" would be used when describing *how* you reached your decision (the process involved).

Comment: @user3169 I'm guessing OP meant "what" :)

Comment: Yes, I really meant "what".